# Loading a file with a relative path in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am writing a C++ program using Qt Creator 3.1.1 in Ubuntu 14.04. This code uses an existing library which loads a file from disk, by passing a string representing a path to that file. The trouble I am having is that when the string represents an absolute path, the file loads fine, but when the string represents a relative path, it fails to load, saying that it cannot find the file.

My project has source files at `/home/karnivaurus/project/src`, and build files at `/home/karnivaurus/project/build`. I have placed a copy of the file `mesh.stl` in each of these directories, and also in the project root directory `/home/karnivaurus/project`. But when I pass the string `../src/mesh.stl`, `../build/mesh.stl`, or `../mesh.stl`, it fails to load. It also fails with `/../src/mesh.stl`, `/../build/mesh.stl`, and`../src/mesh.stl`, `../build/mesh.stl`, or `../mesh.stl`.

However, it does find the file if I pass the strings `/home/karnivaurus/project/src/mesh.stl`, `/home/karnivaurus/project/build/mesh.stl` or `/home/karnivaurus/project/mesh.stl`.

Why is this? Is it a problem with my understanding of relative paths in C++? Or is it something I need to configure in Qt Creator? In my Qt Creator settings, I have the working directory set to `/home/karnivaurus/project/build`.

The exact line I use to load the mesh is:

```
const aiScene* mesh = MeshLib::loadMesh("../mesh.stl");
```

And the corresponding error message is:

```
Failed opening file '/mesh.stl' for reading: No such file or directory
```

This error message is suspicious to me because `/mesh.stl` is not equivalent to `../mesh.stl`...

Comment: Can you verify that the working folder at run-time is indeed the project folder as you are assuming here? One way to do it is to write a file to the path `./dummy.txt` and later see where the file was created.

Comment: I have tried writing a file to `dummy.txt`, and it wrote it to `/home/karnivaurus/project/build/dummy.txt` as expected. (same with `./dummy.txt`)

Comment: How exactly do you load the .stl file? Can you share the line of code where you try to open the file?

Comment: The line is: `const aiScene* mesh = MeshLib::LoadMesh("mesh.stl");`, or `const aiScene* mesh = MeshLib::LoadMesh("../build/mesh.stl");`, etc...

Comment: This is wierd. I'd look into `LoadMesh` to see if they do anything special with the given file path... Have you also tried `./../build/mesh.stl`?

Comment: Passing `./../build/mesh.stl` gives me the error: `Failed opening file '/../build/mesh.stl' for reading: No such file or directory`. Yes, it looks like `LoadMesh()` is a bit dodgy then, but I don't have the source. I will have to keep to absolute paths for now then!

Comment: Are you sure about the directory in which you are? `use QDir::currentPath()` to check. You can keep internally relative paths and then you can then use Qt `QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath()` to convert it to absolute path.

Comment: Find you binary file in your project directory; most probably it's in a subdir of `project/build/`. This is usually the working dir Creator sets when executing the binary. Then use the path from there to the file you want to open. You can also use `QDir().absolutePath()` to determine the working dir of your binary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've already made sure that the working directory is correct. Given that that possibility is eliminated, what's left is a bug in the 3rd party library.

You can construct an absolute path using Qt:

```
QString meshPath = QDir().filePath("../mesh.stl"); 
const aiScene* mesh = MeshLib::loadMesh(meshPath.toLatin1().data());
```

This could serve as work-around until developers of the library fix the bug.

Comment: Or you could use `QDir().absoluteFilePath("../mesh.stl")` to pass an absolute path to MeshLib.